# Why is the responsiveness of my page not working properly?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, responsive

so I have this page made in React which I have set to have a width of 90% when the width drops below 1000px but the width seems to not be dropping as a percentage. It looks fine until 700px but then it doesn't change its size.

Here content of this page:

```
const Form = () => {
    return (
        <div className='div-container'>
            <div className="form-container">
                <div className='div-child toggle-button'>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='toggle' className='toggleCheckbox' value='report' />
                    <label htmlFor='toggle' className='toggleContainer'>
                        <div>Report Bug</div>
                        <div>General Form</div>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div className='div-child formular'>
                    <form>
                        <label htmlFor="fname">Name</label>
                        <input name='Name' className='name' type="text" id="fname" required='true' >

                        </input>
                        <label htmlFor="fmail">Email*</label>
                        <input name='Mail' className='mail' type="email" id="fmail" required='true' >

                        </input>
                        <label>Game*</label>
                        <select name='Game' className='game'>
                            <option value='game1'>Game1</option>
                            <option value='game2'>Game2</option>
                            <option value='game3'>Game3</option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Category*</label>
                        <select name='Categ' className='category'>
                            <option value='categ1'>Categ1</option>
                            <option value='categ2'>Categ2</option>
                            <option value='categ3'>Categ3</option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Description</label>
                        <textarea name='Msg' className='description' cols='5' rows='5' placeholder='Write your message here...'>

                        </textarea>
                        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div className='div-child media'>
                <strong>Connect with us on Social Media</strong>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
                <p>Connect on Facebook</p>
                <p>Connect on Twitter</p>
                <p>Connect on Steam</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

And here is the CSS:

```
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.toggle-button{
    background-color: aqua;
}

.formular{
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

.media{
    background-color: blue;
}

.div-child{
    margin-right: 2%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}


input, select, textarea{
    padding: 1%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px;
    border-style:solid;
}

button{
    background-color: #111111;
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border: solid #111111;
    margin-left: 25%;
    padding: 2%;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px){
    .img_game{
        display: none;
    }
}

/*grid*/
.div-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "toggle-button" "formular media";
    column-gap: 100px;
    row-gap: 100px;
}
.form-container{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
    justify-content: center;
}
.div-child{
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
    justify-content: center;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .div-container {
        width: 90%;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
        column-gap: 100px;
        row-gap: 100px;
    }
    .form-container{
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 2;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 2;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    label, input, select, textarea, button, p, strong{
        font-size: 200%;
        min-height: 6rem;
        resize: vertical;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;
        margin-bottom: 5rem;
        
    }
    .div-child{
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 2;
        grid-row-start: 2;
        grid-row-end: 3;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}



/*end grid*/
```

Here are some previews at full screen, and width 800 and 400:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change :

```
@media only screen and
```

to :

```
@media all screen and
```

Comment: It stayed the same. I added a new media max-width to somewhat solve the problem but it still looks a bit weird.

Comment: maybe add some container whice will be as wrapper to the page. the padding of the contianer will give some space to the page from the inside.